# How can I use TextField in PaginatedDataTable?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am writing a simple application where I wanted to use the Table. I want that Table has TextField in cells and now if I write something, it will tell if that value is correct or incorrect. I created a DataTable class.

```
class VDataTable extends DataTableSource {

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  DataRow? getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          onSubmitted: (value) {
            if (value.isNotEmpty && value == data[index]["A"].toString()) {
              print('Correct');
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement isRowCountApproximate
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  // TODO: implement rowCount
  int get rowCount => strVerbsData.length;

  @override
  // TODO: implement selectedRowCount
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
}
```

Then in the main file, I am using PaginatedDataTable.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final DataTableSource _data = VDataTable();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            PaginatedDataTable(columns: const [
              DataColumn(label: Text("A")),
              DataColumn(label: Text("B")),
            ], source: _data),
          ],
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

Now, issue is that I cannot edit a single cell (TextField). It shows textfield in all the cells and all cells shows same text. Any solution?

[image: Table Fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have 1 single TextEditingController. The TextEditingController holds the text for the TextField, if you change now 1 single TextField, all will change.

You have to create a new TextEditingController for each TextField. So just use a `List<TextEditingController> textEditingController`.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Or Edit my answer because I am getting an error.

Comment: Which error? Edit your changes and show your error message.

Comment: Because this is a list of TextEditingController. I need to initialize it first and then use it. If I initialise it after " DataRow? getRow(int index) {" then I get an error.